# Erro Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, pdo

Bom estou com um objeto 'X' que uma das propriedades dele é um JSON. Neste JSON contem o nome da coluna e o valor da coluna respectivamente.

Porem posso ter vários objetos 'X', e por ai vai.
Hoje estou dazendo da seguinte forma:

PHP:

```
 public function SincronizaBanco_MobileWeb(array $params = NULL) {
    $objeto = json_decode($this->params['objJSON']);
    $tamanho = count($objeto);

    try {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $tamanho; $i++) {
            if ($objeto[$i]->FLG_IDENT_OPERA == 'I') {
                $inputs = array();
                $inputsJSON = $objeto[$i]->TXT_COLUN_SINCR;
                $inputs[':values'] = json_decode($inputsJSON);

                print_r($inputs);

                $sincronismo = $this->conexao->save("INSERT INTO " + $objeto[$i]->TXT_TABLE_SINCR + " values (:values);", $inputs);
            } else if ($objeto[$i]->FLG_IDENT_OPERA == 'U') {

            } else {

            }
        }
        print_r("Inserção concluido com sucesso !");
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
}
```

Está dando o seguinte erro:

> [Sat Dec 05 09:22:57 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.248] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/conexao.php on line 53, referer: http://127.0.0.1:58889/

O erro ocorre na seguinte função:

```
    public function execute(PDOStatement $stmt, array $data = null) {
    try {
        if (isset($data)) {
            $stmt->execute($data);
        } else {
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
        var_dump($exc->getMessage());
    }
}
```

E o que chama esta função é

```
    public function save($sql, array $data) {

    $con = self::getConnection();

    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
    print_r($stmt);
    $this->execute($stmt, $data);

    if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Como faço para resolver isto ?

Meu array depois do json_decode está assim:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [COD_IDENT_SINCR] => 1
            [TXT_TABLE_SINCR] => tbl_PESSOAS
            [FLG_IDENT_OPERA] => I
            [TXT_COLUN_SINCR] => {"COD_IDENT_PESSO":"1151205091356692","TXT_NOMEX_PESSO":"iyuiyui","TXT_APELI_PESSO":"yuiyuiy","FLG_SEXOX_PESSO":"","DAT_NASCI_PESSO":"","TXT_NASCI_PESSO":"","TXT_NATUR_PESSO":"","FLG_ESTAD_CIVIL":"S","TXT_FONEX_PESSO":"","FLG_IDENT_PESSO":"A","TXT_EMAIL_PESSO":"","TXT_SENHA_PESSO":"","TXT_ENDER_CEPXX":"","TXT_ENDER_LOGRA":"","TXT_ENDER_BAIRR":"","TXT_ENDER_NUMER":"","TXT_ENDER_COMPL":""}
            [TXT_WHERE_SINCR] => 
            [FLG_IDENT_SINCR] => N
            [COD_IDULT_ATUAL] => -1
            [DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL] => 2015-11-05 09:13:56
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [COD_IDENT_SINCR] => 2
            [TXT_TABLE_SINCR] => tbl_PESSOA_TURMA
            [FLG_IDENT_OPERA] => I
            [TXT_COLUN_SINCR] => {"COD_IDENT_PESSO":"1151205091356692","COD_IDENT_CELUL":"1","FLG_IDENT_PESSO":"M","COD_IDULT_ATUAL":"-1","DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL":"2015-11-05 09:13:56"}
            [TXT_WHERE_SINCR] => 
            [FLG_IDENT_SINCR] => N
            [COD_IDULT_ATUAL] => -1
            [DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL] => 2015-11-05 09:13:56
        )

)
```

Comment: Porquê voltaste a criar outro método `execute` sendo que o próprio PDO já traz um consigo ? E `$data` é uma instância de `array` ?

Comment: Coloca o script completo no _pastebin_ juntamente com o ficheiro _json_.

Comment: Não entendi Edilson

Comment: Tu criaste outro método [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), sendo que o próprio PDO já traz um consigo. E estás a declarar tipos para os argumentos.

Comment: Mais o problema não está ai, preciso disto, para ter segurança em que parte do código está.

Comment: Que seja. Pedi também que mostrasses o resto do script. E troca o nome do teu método `execute` para outra coisa.

Comment: Porem eu sei aonde está o problema... O erro occorre porque preciso definir um array de objetos e preciso salvar isto. O restante está file. Me ajude nesta questão.

Comment: O script do php ?

Comment: Porque tudo que envolve neste erro está postado ai.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, veja la

Comment: Visto assim, o problema parece estar no primeiro loop `for`, onde constróis a array que contém os valores. Vou analisar melhor, respondo assim que puder.

Comment: Olha o problema está mesmo na forma como montas a array para inserir. Da coluna `[TXT_COLUN_SINCR]` quais valores pretendes inserir ? Apenas um ou todos no mesmo campo do banco de dados ?

Comment: Preciso inserir todos, esses valores são referentes aos valores que tem la na tabela.

Comment: `COD_IDENT_PESSO` e os outros índices são campos da tabela ?

Comment: Sim, todos são campos da tabela

Comment: Era essa pergunta, felizmente a resposta abaixo já respondeu isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

O erro acontece quando você tenta manipular um tipo composto(array ou objeto) em um string ou tenta imprimir algum deles com `print` ou `echo`.

`save()` recebe um string(comando SQL) e tenta executar a operação no banco, porém o simbolo para concatenar strings é `.` e não `+`

```
$sincronismo = $this->conexao->save("INSERT INTO " + $objeto[$i]->TXT_TABLE_SINCR + " values (:values);", $inputs);
```

Eu rescreveria a lógica do método para simplificar algumas coisas e deixar mais claro outros.

Trocaria o `for` convecional por um `foreach` para eliminar a vairável `$tamanho` e trocar as insutrções `$objeto[$i]->algo` por `$item->algo`.

Talvez não tenha ficado claro na pergunta mas `TXT_COLUN_SINCR` parece ser o registro a ser gravado no banco de dados entretanto ele está como um json então é necessário converte-lo sua estrutura fica dessa forma:

```
Array
(
    [COD_IDENT_PESSO] => 1151205091356692
    [TXT_NOMEX_PESSO] => iyuiyui
    [TXT_APELI_PESSO] => yuiyuiy
    [FLG_SEXOX_PESSO] => 
    [DAT_NASCI_PESSO] => 
    [TXT_NASCI_PESSO] => 
    [TXT_NATUR_PESSO] => 
    [FLG_ESTAD_CIVIL] => S
    [TXT_FONEX_PESSO] => 
    [FLG_IDENT_PESSO] => A
    [TXT_EMAIL_PESSO] => 
    [TXT_SENHA_PESSO] => 
    [TXT_ENDER_CEPXX] => 
    [TXT_ENDER_LOGRA] => 
    [TXT_ENDER_BAIRR] => 
    [TXT_ENDER_NUMER] => 
    [TXT_ENDER_COMPL] => 
)
```

A ideia é basicamente montar a consulta corretamente, primeiro `json_decode()` em `$item->TXT_COLUN_SINCR` para retornar o array acima, a partir dele monto a lista de campos e binds com a instrução: 
`$campos = implode(',', array_keys($json));` o que muda é a lista de binds tem `:` antes do nome campos.

Com a lista de campos e binds pronta é só coloca-las na string que contém a SQL, com `sprintf()`, cada `%s` é substituido por cada valor na ordem, o primeiro coloca o nome da tabela, o segundo a lista de campos e último os binds.

```
public function SincronizaBanco_MobileWeb(array $params = NULL) {
    $objeto = json_decode($this->params['objJSON']);
    try{
        foreach($objeto as $item){
            if($item->FLG_IDENT_OPERA == 'I'){
                $json = json_decode($item->TXT_COLUN_SINCR, true);
                $campos = implode(',', array_keys($json));
                $binds = ':'. implode(',:', array_keys($json));

                $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)", $item->TXT_TABLE_SINCR, $campos, $binds);
                $sincronismo = $this->conexao->save($sql, $json);

            } else if ($objeto[$i]->FLG_IDENT_OPERA == 'U') {
            }else{
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

Outra alternativa ao segundo `implode()` é o uso do `str_replace()` para remover os `:`.

```
$binds = ':'. implode(',:', array_keys($json));
$campos = str_replace(':', '', $binds);
```

Comment: No caso amigo como ficaria o de update ? Estou tentando fazer aqui porem sempre da o mesmo erro `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ` E o problema está na minha SQL