# Problema com UPDATE dinâmico em PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estou criando um **CRUD** dinâmico em [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo), onde recebo vários parâmetros dentro de um array, e dentro destes array podem haver vários outros arrays. O problema está aparece quando estou montando a SQL.

Fiz uma pergunta semelhante [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102154/erro-object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string), porém a solução não foi padronizada, está acusando erro:

> #5 {main}string(100) "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Meu código PHP está desta assim:

```
  $campos = json_decode($item->TXT_COLUN_SINCR, true);
  $campos = implode(' = ?, ', array_keys($campos));
  $valores = json_decode($item->TXT_COLUN_SINCR, true);
  $sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s %s ", $item->TXT_TABLE_SINCR, $campos, $item->TXT_WHERE_SINCR);
  $sincronismo = $this->conexao->save($sql, $valores);
```

Meu array $campos:

```
Array
(
    [COD_IDENT_IGREJ] => IBM
    [COD_IDENT_CELUL] => 1
    [COD_IDENT_PESSO] => 120151202162837
    [DAT_INICI_PARTC] => 0000-00-00
    [FLG_IDENT_PESSO] => M
    [FLG_STATU_PARTC] => A
    [DAT_FINAL_PARTC] => 
    [MEM_OBSRV_ADCNS] => 
    [COD_IDULT_ATUAL] => 1
    [DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL] => 2015-12-05 15:14:26
    [COD_CELUL_PESSO] => 4
)
```

Detalhes para o erro de parâmetro:

```
Array 
( 
[COD_IDENT_IGREJ] => IBM 
[COD_IDENT_CELUL] => 1 
[COD_IDENT_PESSO] => 120151202162837 
[DAT_INICI_PARTC] => 0000-00-00 
[FLG_IDENT_PESSO] => M 
[FLG_STATU_PARTC] => A 
[DAT_FINAL_PARTC] => 
[MEM_OBSRV_ADCNS] => 
[COD_IDULT_ATUAL] => 1 
[DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL] => 2015-12-05 15:14:26 
[COD_CELUL_PESSO] => 4 
) 
PDOStatement Object 
( 
[queryString] => UPDATE tbl_PESSOA_CELULA SET COD_IDENT_IGREJ = ?, COD_IDENT_CELUL = ?, COD_IDENT_PESSO = ?, DAT_INICI_PARTC = ?, FLG_IDENT_PESSO = ?, FLG_STATU_PARTC = ?, DAT_FINAL_PARTC = ?, MEM_OBSRV_ADCNS = ?, COD_IDULT_ATUAL = ?, DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL = ?, COD_CELUL_PESSO= ? WHERE COD_IDENT_PESSO = '120151202162837' and COD_IDENT_CELUL = '1' and COD_IDENT_IGREJ = 'ibm' 
)
```

Comment: Qual erro obténs ?

Comment: #5 {main}string(282) "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ibm' '120151202162837' 'Hadailton de Sousa Carvalho' 'Hadailton' '31988696771' ' at line 1"

Comment: So que na verdade o problema está ao montar a query

Comment: Faça o seguinte, no método `save`, comenta as linhas que se seguem à `$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);`, e coloca um `var_dump($stmt)`.

Comment: O resultado é aquele sql que coloquei a cima. O problema está acontecendo quando eu estou gerando o sql. irei comentar a linha, sei que é porem não sei resolver.

Comment: Ele está montando sql assim `UPDATE tbl_PESSOAS SET VALOR 1, VALOR 2, :solucao1, solucao2` deveria fica assim `UPDATE tbl_PESSOA SET valor 1 =  :solucao1, valor 2 = :solucao2` Porem é isto que não estou conseguindo desenvolver.

Comment: `$campos = explode(',', $campos); $binds = explode(',', $binds);` e depois faça isto `var_dump(array_combine($binds, $campos))`.

Comment: Ok irei testar, que fazer uma resposta para caso alguem ja tenha duvida ?

Comment: Seria escusado responder sem ter a certeza de que foi esta solução. Ficarei antes à espera do teu retorno, e depois veremos se foi mesmo esta a solução ou ainda há mais.

Comment: É realmente não funcionou

Comment: @Edilson Eu editei a pergunta para vc ver o resultado

Comment: Estás a montar mal.

Comment: Sim, a dificuldade está ai

Comment: Vale lembra que eu ja tenho um array onde tenho o [VALOR] = SOLUÇÃO

Comment: Como eu descrevi na pergunta anterior do meu exemplo. Dê uma olhada la.

Comment: A sintaxe do select está errada, o problema nao é nem de PHP nem de PDO. Experimente fazer um select manualmente direto no DB.

Comment: Do jeito que isso está é meio complicado trabalhar, ficar adicionando partes de código onde não deveria sequer haver mais código, experimenta isto - http://pastebin.com/bhsbVxT8

Comment: Qual é a PK(campo) par fazer o update?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é a sintaxe que está errada, o update deve ser:

```
UPDATE tabela SET campo = valor, campo = valor WHERE id = id
```

É possível remodelar o código, a ideia é cortar o primeiro elemento do array(acredito que seja a chave primária) e usar o `implode()` para gerar a string no formato `campo = ?,`.

Mudei o nome `$json` para `$campos`

```
$campos = json_decode($item->TXT_COLUN_SINCR, true);
$pk = array_slice($valores, 0, 1); //extrai a pk e seu valor
$campos = implode(' = ?, ', array_keys($campos));
$where  = sprintf("%s = %s", key($pk), $pk['COD_IDENT_IGREJ']);
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s ", 'tabela', $campos, $where);
```